# fetching data from different endpoint in react router

Tags: fetch, react-router-dom

"I have a `DataTable` component composed of three other components named table, pagination, and search. The `DataTable` component is located in the `HomePage`, and its data is fetched using server-side rendering. To fetch the data, I have set a base URL since this table component will be used in various places, and depending on which endpoint is requested, different data will be displayed in the table.

Now, in the `HomePage`, I have a link called 'user,' and when I click on it, the `DataTable` component is rendered and displays the data. Below this link, I have two more links named `'confirm'` and `'removed'`. When I click on any of these links, I want a different endpoint to be requested, and the data related to each of them to be displayed inside the table. However, I'm not sure how to define this. I don't want the `DataTable` component to be re-rendered; I just want to request a different endpoint and populate the table with the corresponding data."

```
          <Route
            index
            element={
              <div>
                <TableComponent
                  rows={[]}
                  emptyRows={[]}
                  handleSort={() => {}}
                  columns={[
                    { key: "id", label: "ID2" },
                    { key: "job", label: "Job2" },
                  ]}
                />
                <Pagination />
              </div>
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="confirm"
            element={<Table />}
          />
          <Route path="remove" element={<Table/>} />
        </Route>
```